# Slot recognition issue with Deep linking in google assistant action builder

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

We created a Google assistant action using action builder. This action has a required slot. The slot is not recognized when the intent is invoked via deep linking. But it works fine when it is invoked in two steps.

Example:

User says: Ask [action name] what is the pressure in [slot value]. -> Google assistant asks for slot value even when the slot value is in the command.

On the other hand, following recognizes the slot value
User: Ask [action name]
GA: Welcome to [action name]. What can I do for you?
User: what is the pressure in [slot value].

In this, the action recognizes the slot value and responds as
"The pressure in [slot value] is ..."

How can we make the invocation via deep linking recognize the slot value?
Thank you!